# iOS 7.1: UITabBarItems have default color

Tags: uitabbaritem

Seems that this line does not work correctly after 7.1 update anymore:

```
NSDictionary *tabBarTitleTextAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.059 green:0.737 blue:0.596 alpha:1.0], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil];
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:tabBarTitleTextAttributes forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.

```
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor redColor]} forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

**My setup**

- iPhone 4s
- XCode 5.1
- iOS 7.1